# Is there a pandas split(expand=True) equivalent in Bigquery function?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, google-bigquery

I'm trying to reproduce the following example in BigQuery :

Starting with the table :

```
ROW                                    VALUE
0                                        AAA
1                                        BBB
2                                     CCC ~ DDD
```

I want to reproduce the behavior of the following in BigQuery:

```py
df["VALUE"].str.split("~",expand=True)
```

which returns :

```
       0             1            
0     AAA          None         
1     BBB          None         
2     CCC          DDD
```

Is there a way to achieve that in BigQuery?

So far I have the following query :

```
SELECT SPLIT(VALUE, "~")
FROM my_dataset.my_table
```

but it returns :

```
Row     f0_     
1   683600749R
    ______________
2   284A92167R
    ______________
3   281150577R 
    
    281154695R
    ______________
```

While I would like to have :

```
Row     f0_           f1_
1   683600749R      None
    ____________________________
2   284A92167R      None
    ____________________________
3   281150577R      281154695R
    ____________________________
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a perfect solution, but to get part 1 and part 2 of split you could write:

```
with tab1 as (
    SELECT NULL as col1
        UNION ALL
    SELECT 'AAA' as col1
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'BBB' as col1
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'CCC ~ DDD'as col1
)
SELECT 
col1,
SPLIT(col1, "~")[OFFSET(0)] AS part_1,
CASE 
    WHEN ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(col1, "~")) < 2 THEN NULL 
    ELSE SPLIT(col1, "~")[OFFSET(1)] 
    END AS part_2
FROM tab1

# output
Row    col1     part_1    part_2
1    null    null    null
2    AAAA    AAAA    null
3    BBBB    BBBB    null
4    CCC ~ DDDD    CCC    DDD
```

If you don't use CASE WHEN to get OFFSET(1) you will have an error `Array index 1 is out of bounds`  when SPLIT will not generate (at least) two parts.